# How to add ios apple-app-site-association

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate

hi everyone~May i ask a question about setting apple-app-site-association.
I want to not open this example.com/getName?id=123&num=4 and queryitem is dynamic
but it still open from the app.
How can i set up the apple-app-site-association.
Please help Thanks
this is my setting.
[mySetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mez2M.png)

1. "/": "/getName*",
   "exclude": true,
   "comment": "Matches this URL not open it"